# Any reason to use or teach `…` substitution for new development?

Tags: shell, command-substitution

It is my understanding that the more modern `$(...)` command substitution syntax is preferred over the old `` ` ``-based syntax, due to easier and less error-prone nesting and escaping syntax.

Further, it seems that most `/bin/sh`-style shells in modern use support `$(…)`:

- bash
- [ash](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/#original) (and therefore BusyBox, so most embedded Linux)
- dash
- FreeBSD /bin/sh

And `$(…)` is specified by IEEE 1003.1.

So I have 2 very related questions:

- Is there any reason to use ` in new development of shell scripts unless you know of a specific old system that the script will need to run on?
- Is there any reason not to teach UNIX programming students just to write `$(...)`, and discuss `` ` `` only as an obsolete variant that they will likely encounter if they are reading other developers' shell scripts (and may need if they are working with a really old system or nonstandard for some reason)?

Comment: No, there's no point using or teaching `\`...\``. It's there for backward portability with the Bourne shell only (like the Bourne shell had `^` (same as `|`) for backward portability with the Thomson shell). Note however that `(t)csh` don't have `$(...)` (but there's no much point using or teaching them either).

Comment: It's a Groucho Marx thing `;{)

Comment: Wait, backticks are deprecated?? Does anybody have a canonical reference explaining why? (Weird syntax characters are very hard to search on.)

Comment: I didn't even know there was a replacement for backticks...  Good info.

Comment: Easier to type. ``  - 2 keys presses; `$()` - shift+4,9, shift+0 - 5 key presses;

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed seems pretty good. Backticks are very difficult to nest properly, especially when additional quotes are involved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since back-ticks are often used, it makes sense to teach this syntactic construct.

Of course, `$()` style command substitution should be emphasized as the default style (and standard conforming construct).

Why are back-ticks still popular? Because they save one character in typing, and they are arguably less heavy on the eye.

Comment: I wouldn't characterise "less heavy on the eye" as a feature, but a bug...

Comment: Normally I use backsticks in simple cases, and $() in complex cases. But very lot scripts are using the backsticks until now, and the grads had to be able to scope with them.

Comment: @jasonwryan In that case the bug is not because of the brevity, but arbitrary issues. I.e., using backticks *is* easier on the eye, but that is not *why* it is depreciated.  Unless you are trying to say sugar is by definition bad and we should all prefer asm for whatever... Actually I like the look of `$()` better but backticks are easier and more K.I.S.S.; could be pavlovian OCDish consequence of general programming.

Comment: @goldilocks once you get older, readability is so much harder anyway: backticks are practically invisible in code at my age...

Comment: On a French keyboard for instance, `\`` is Altrg+è, (awkward to type), while `$`, `(`, `)` don't need any modifier.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, hm, but `$()` all need the shift modifier on a french keyboard, still? On a US keyboard the backtick does not need any modifier at all. Thus, on a US-keyboard, with backticks you have to touch just 2 keys, with `$()` you have to touch 6 keys (including the shift modifier) -> thrice as much! :D

Comment: No. `$()` don't need shift or any other modifier on a french keyboard.

Comment: I would like to say that easy on the eye is a poor argument. The bracketed version is far more easily recognizable and harder to disguise , so it improves code readability

Answer (score 5):

I would not use them for programming, and teaching the use of backtick substitution in shell scripts as obsolete is fine (this seems to be the consensus). I don't think they're inherently evil, however, and (at least judging by your average tutorial to Linux command line) they are still frequently used in simple snippets/one-liners where they probably won't be nested and things you're only going to do once.

See [Command substitution: backticks or dollar sign / paren enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed).

Answer (score 1):

I avoid using the `$()` construct because it is not portable - in the real world. You have listed four shells - there are a lot more variations than that around (an order of magnitude?). Try running your script in Solaris /bin/sh and see how you go.

On the other hand, when do you stop supporting old systems? can you never progress to new ways of doing things? I reckon you should trust your own judgement, and if you can see a definite advantage of the new way over the old, then go for it ... this is not one of them (personally I find the bacticks much clearer - they cannot be confused with shell variable substitution, which is a different thing)

Comment: POSIX does not specify that `/bin/sh` must be conforming. The Solaris `/bin/sh` is indeed very non-conforming - although Solaris 9/10/... are officially POSIX compliant. The `$()` is just one construct it does not understand. But there are many more it doesn't understand or are interpreted differently. The portable way to get a conforming `sh` to search for it in the path returned by `getconf PATH`.