# When should one use $( ) in defining variables

Tags: shell, variable, command-substitution

Some shell scripts I have come across use the following syntax when defining variables:

`file_list_1=$(echo "list.txt")`

or

`file_list_2=$(find ./)`

I would have used:

```
file_list_1="list.txt"
```

and

```
file_list_2=`find ./`
```

I'm not sure which if any of the above are better or safer. What is the benefit of using the syntax `x=$( )` when setting a variable?

Comment: See [What’s the difference between $(stuff) and \`stuff \`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/80216) and [Any reason to use or teach \`…\` substition for new development?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180351/80216)

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `file_list_1=$(echo "list.txt")` instead of `file_list_1="list.txt"`. That would be slower (unnecessary `echo` command), more error prone (in case of special characters) and less readable. I would use single quotes however: `file_list_1='list.txt'` - that would be even more solid.

Comment: The short version: nesting anq quoting `\`...\`` is a pain, while `$(...)` is a lot saner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the manual (`man bash`):

> `$(`*command*`)`  or  `` ` ``*command*`` ` ``
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing *command* and replacing the command  substitution  with  the  standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they   may  be  removed during word splitting.
>   The command substitution `$(cat` *file*`)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(<` *file*`)`.
>
> When the old-style backquote form of substitution  is  used,  backslash  retains  its  literal  meaning except when followed by `$`, `` ` ``, or `\`.
>   The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command  substitution.   When using the `$(`*command*`)` form, all characters between the  parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

The POSIX standard defines the `$()` form of command substitution. `$()`
allows nested commands and looks better (legibility). It should be available on all [Bourne shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).

You can read more on IEEE Std 1003.1, Shell Command Language, [Section 2.6.3 Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03).

At least one Unix, AIX, has documented that [backticks are obsolete](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_comm_sub.htm). From that link:

> Although the backquote syntax is accepted by ksh, it is considered obsolete by the X/Open Portability Guide Issue 4 and POSIX standards. These standards recommend that portable applications use the $(command) syntax.

However, `/bin/sh` does not have to be POSIX compliant. So there is still sometimes a case for backticks in the real world, as @Jeight points out.

Comment: Is there any point in using command substitution to define a variable statically, as in `file_list_1=$(echo "list.txt")`? Maybe for special characters?

Comment: I take it you don't work with older UNIX systems that often? Obsolete maybe by modern standards yes.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to come across so harsh. I just have to create backward compatible scripts everyday. This is by far the better and more complete answer.

Comment: @Jeight No - no. not at all! I knew exactly what you meant in your answer. I did not down-vote you. U&L SE seems brutal sometimes, but it is much less of a goat rodeo than "the other" SE site. :) I am actually waiting for a better answer, because I know there are people here who could answer better.

Comment: (I don't have the reputation to upvote but I do appreciate the help from both of you, and @G-Man of course!)

Comment: @Christopher: You say “The POSIX standard defines the `$()` form of command substitution. `$()` allows nested commands”.  True.  Also, the POSIX standard defines the `\`…\`` form of command substitution, and `\`…\`` allows nested commands (``cmd₃ … `cmd₂ … \`cmd₁ …\` …` …``).

Comment: @G-Man; With backtics nesting requires escapes, as you've showed. - How would another level of nesting be implemented? How would consistent double-quoting on each level be implemented? - Short answer; use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: @Christopher; You are technically right that `/bin/sh` may be an old bourne shell (in the 1970's and early 1980's). But have you seen such systems in the past two decades? - Even in the 1990's the commercial systems (e.g. AIX, HP-UX) usually have `sh` linked to a `ksh` (`ksh88`), which was the base for POSIX and supported `$(...)`.

Comment: @Janis IKR? No, I have never actually seen one, and I started in 92!

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot of personal preference. Using a backtick to signify a command would be more POSIX compatible with older systems. The $() is more modern and is easier to read for some people. I would personally never use `file_list_1=$(echo "list.txt")`. It seems to ugly and has no additional use.

Comment: That's not correct.

Comment: @DisplayName Really? Why don't you clarify? The answer from CHristopher is referring to bash, but what if you are using an older HPUX that uses sh or ksh... is $() POSIX compatible then? The only thing I left out was the litteral meaning of the entire command when using $() and not backticks. That can cause problems when you have nested quotations in your command. So like I said a lot of personal preference.

Comment: I did mean all Bourne shells (ash, bash, dash, zsh, etc), not just the Bourne Again Shell (BASH).

Comment: I understand, but you are talking modern shells, and I'm including older shells as well such as csh and sh. Look at http://www.efytimes.com/e1/creativenews.asp?edid=123101

Comment: So no, $() is not always POSIX compatible with older UNIX systems.

Comment: @Jeight; There's confusing and misleading text above; "more POSIX compatible" ("more"?) and "is $() POSIX compatible" - those make no sense. - Note that `$(...)` **is** defined by POSIX, and any shell claiming to be POSIX compatible has to support it. Note also that older commercial Unixes (e.g. AIX, HP-UX) had ksh88, and ksh88 supported not only `$(...)` but invented it, and moreover, ksh88 was also the base for the POSIX definition. - The backtics, OTOH, have issues (see references), though, and are deprecated; there's no reason to use them, but reasons to abstain from using them.