# Why alias behave different than running bash command directly?

Tags: bash, alias

I’m trying to create an alias to open up my log fie

```
alias open_log='date=`date +%y%m%d`;sudo tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$date.log;'
```

When I run that alias

`open_log`

I got

> tail: cannot open ‘/home/benu/logs/reconfig-.log’ for reading: No such file or directory

But if I run

"*what I set for that alias*"

```
date=`date +%y%m%d`;sudo tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$date.log;
```

It works perfectly fine.

```
+ service iptables save
iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables: [  OK  ]
+ mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available
+ cp /root/portal-data/sites-available/default-https /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
+ '[' '!' -f /etc/ssl/mywifibusiness.trg.telenet.be.cert.pem ']'
+ echo 'Error: Unable to find certificate at /etc/ssl/mywifibusiness.trg.telenet.be.cert.pem'
Error: Unable to find certificate at /etc/ssl/mywifibusiness.trg.telenet.be.cert.pem
+ exit 1
Error: Executing /home/benu/reconfig.d/70-ssc-portal.sh returned 1
Reconfigure aborted
```

Why they’re behaving different ? Can anyone elaborate ?

How do I fix my alias to make it work ?

Comment: `alias open_log="sudo tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$(date +%y%m%d).log"`

Comment: The only system I have access to is an Ubuntu system, and this seems to work there. @Christopher I don't think OP wants weak quotes here

Comment: I even tried `date=`date +%y%m%d`; echo -e  "~/logs/reconfig-$date.log" | sudo tail -n 10;` , but it does is printing out my path command, rather than running that command. How do I fix it guys ?

Comment: Works for me, though setting a variable in an alias a bit weird (it stays set in the outside context). Do you have an alias or function overriding `date` or something like that?

Comment: Why would you want to open a file in your home directory as root? Why not just `alias open_log="tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$(date +%y%m%d).log;"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, @ihue. I got this wrong to start. Kudos to @ilkkachu.

Compare the alias with the command line, posted before the edit:

```
alias 'date=date +%y%m%d;sudo tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$date.log;'
date=`date +%y%m%d`;sudo tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$date.log;
```

The alias is missing the backticks. Also, the backticks are [all but antiquated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204949/when-should-one-use-in-defining-variables/204952#204952). Use the following form for command substitution: `$(command)`.

Double quotes work as follows, which sets the date each time the alias was set.

```
alias open_log="sudo tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$(date +%y%m%d).log"
```

Single quotes work dynamically, setting the date each time you call the alias.

```
alias open_log='sudo tail -n 10 ~/logs/reconfig-$(date +%y%m%d).log'
```

Comment: That alias, with the double-quotes, would expand the command substitution at the time the alias is set, not when it's executed.

Comment: Please note the accurate comment by @ilkkachu. In other words, every time you source your aliases, however that may be - at log in time or manually, perhaps - the date is set at that time, not dynamically every time you call the alias.

Comment: ...of course with single-quotes it would be the opposite, compare `alias d1='echo $(date +%T)' d2="echo $(date +%T)"`

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu. I had the wrong understanding to start.