# Setting an alias when double quotes and single quotes both fail

Tags: vim, quoting, alias, bashrc

*This question is not a duplicate of [Why alias behave different than running bash command directly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363056/why-alias-behave-different-than-running-bash-command-directly) because I have tried that solution and it hasn't worked. I replaced all my single quotes with double quotes and vice-versa. The command works neither way.*

I am trying to implement an alias, `sys`, that will open a file I keep track of changes to my system in, `sys.md`, append a date, yank that line, paste the line, replace it with `-`'s for the markdown h2 format, open a new line, and insert a `-` for the markdown bullet format. From vi.stackexchange.com I received some help implementing the command. It works:

```
nvim +'$pu_|r!date' +'norm yypVr-o ' ~/notes/sys.md
```

When I replace the single quotes with double quotes the $pu_ is evaluated and I get

```
zsh: event not found: date
```

So the single quotes are important. However, when I implement the alias

```
alias sys="nvim +'$pu_|r!date' +'norm yypVr-o- ' ~/notes/sys.md"
```

The alias fails. `nvim` opens , but the date is appended to the second line and not the bottom. Clearly $pu_ is being evaluated as a variable from BASH. (`nvim`'s syntax checker even shows it to be evaluated.) Inverting the doubles and singles to yield

```
alias sys='nvim +"$pu_|r!date" +"norm yypVr-o- " ~/notes/sys.md'
```

Has the same behavior. Backticks,

```
alias sys=`nvim +"$pu_|r!date" +"norm yypVr-o- " ~/notes/sys.md`
```

Freezes bash on `source .zshrc`. I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does escaping the `$` in `$pu_`  not work?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it into a bash function (you can add the function to `.bashrc`):

```
sys() {
    nvim +'$pu_|r!date' +'norm yypVr-o ' ~/notes/sys.md
}
```

Then you can invoke it just like you would do this with an alias.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up reforming the command to avoid the `$pu_` variable but this is a brilliant work around and I think deserves the answer acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is to understand how to have a `single quote` character inside a single quoted string, here is the method. Use:

```
'\''
```

for the `single quote` character inside the single quoted string.

This ends the current quoted string, then inserts a quoted quote and then starts a new quoted string.

BTW: since this is a frequent problem, `bosh` comes with a method to automate this conversion. You could fetch `schilytools` and compile them and then play with `bosh`. If you call:

```
set -o hashcmds
#b aliasname aliasreplacement
```

The value in `aliasreplacement` is entered in `raw` mode and if you later call:

```
alias aliasname
```

you see the alias in the correctly quoted form and if you enter

```
alias -R aliasname
```

you see the alias in `raw` mode.

Comment: You're saying there's no `BASH` solution?  I thought of escaping the `'` but didn't try it until you mentioned it. And yeah, it doesn't work.

Comment: If this escaping really does not work in bash, then you should make a bug report. I however guess that you did not follow my example.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Escaping all the single quotes did not solve the problem, it merely changed it. I cannot recall the exact error message. weirdan's solution worked around the `BASH` quoting and variable evaluation problems with the command in particular in a simple manner and so I accepted it. I am not going to install software packages with limited support in my operating system (`bosh` is in the `aur` only and I try to avoid the `aur`; `schilytools` isn't even available except from your sourceforge) in order to solve a problem when there's a simpler solution.

Comment: You do not need to follow my advise, but I believe schilytools are important on a Linux installation, sice they give you e.g. a SHA3 aware hash program, a correctly working tar and a POSIX certified make program. If your distro does not include these programs, you may like to ask your distro why this is missing.