# Cut works with echo but not without it

Tags: linux, bash, files, echo, cut

So I am trying to extract an output similar to

```
x=($discover nginx --human=nood)
```

which gives me an output like

> i-03099   nginx   IP  noodlefish      pip b4b966d280546c6b070f5f952c281d3294308048

Further I want to extract the pip column in another variable. 
When I do

```
echo "$x" | cut -f6
```

I get my desired output, but when I try.

```
y= "$x" | cut -f6
```

I get a blank output.

Please can you explain me why is this happening and how can I get the result I want. Thank you in advance.

Comment: y="$x" doesn't produce any output, so there's nothing to cut.

Comment: Is the output of the command in `$discover` tab delimited? Why don't you pass it through `cut` immediately? `x=("$discover" nginx --human=nood | cut -f 6)` or `x=$("$discover" nginx --human=nood | awk '{ print $NF }')`

Comment: is "cut f-6" a typo in there?

Answer (score 1):

> Further I want to extract the pip column in another variable. When I
>   do
>
> `echo "$x" | cut -f6`
>
> I get my desired output[...]

That's weird, because this should not work, since

```
‘-f FIELD-LIST’
‘--fields=FIELD-LIST’
     Select for printing only the fields listed in FIELD-LIST.  Fields
     are separated by a TAB character by default.  Also print any line
     that contains no delimiter character, unless the ‘--only-delimited’
     (‘-s’) option is specified.
```

`-f` should work only when fields are separated by TAB, unless `-d` sets it otherwise.

If you want to extract the field after the word `pip`, such script works for me

```
x="i-03099 nginx IP noodlefish pip b4b966d280546c6b070f5f952c281d3294308048"

y=$(echo -n "$x" | cut -d ' ' -f 6 -)

echo "$y"
```

Comment: I think it is already tab separated. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

Use below command

```
y=`echo $x |cut -f6`
```

Comment: Backtics are not a modern practice: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204949/when-should-one-use-in-defining-variables/204952#204952

Comment: and variables should be quoted...

Comment: I didnt know that was a back tick. Thank you